# Cannot delete child from set in Hibernate even with using orphanRemoval = true

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue that even if I delete an element from @OneToMany relation set, it keeps in database. I tried Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true etc. but still couldn't find the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Parent extends JpaBaseEntity {

    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();



    public Parent(ParentSO parentSO) {
        .....
        this.getChildren().clear();
        this.getChildren().addAll(parentSO.getChildren(this));
        .....
    }

.....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Child extends JpaBaseEntity {

    .....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    .....
}


Parent parent = new Parent(parentSO);
subsDao.updateParent(parent);
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No I don't @SimonMartinelli

Comment: What is the `ParentSO` object?

Comment: Where is your delete method call?

Comment: ParentSO is the object which is filled by user on client side. It is pretty much the same as Parent. @Aris.

Comment: Child is deleted on client side and new children list without that child is added to ParentSO object. Then, parent object takes the children list from ParentSO object. @Kartik

Comment: This should like an extremely tiresome process to perform. Assuming that you're performing this in the context of REST API (client), why not just expose an endpoint for deleting a single or a batch of children objects? I think that all your problems stem from this bad design approach.

Comment: Actually there are some differences between Parent and ParentSO, and even if this design approach is bad, I still can't see why this code does not work. @Aris